# Why won't the SQL Query run?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Right Click Data Connections.
2. Added a connection to the server.
3. Selected Microsoft SQL Server (SQL Client).
4. Created the database.
5. Right clicked the tables section.
6. Pressed Add New Query.
7. Inserted the SQL statement.
8. Pressed Execute SQL statement.

I used this SQL statement to try and run it:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Title](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [artist] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [price] [money] NULL,
    [length] [float] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_title] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ( [id] ASC )
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Dhoom Machale', N'Aditi Singh Sharma', CAST(5.99 AS Money), 7.45)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Mat Maari', N'Kunal Ganjawala, Sunidhi Chauhan', CAST(4.50 AS Money), 6.45)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Paani Paani',N'Honey Singh', CAST(2.90 AS Money), 4.5)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Dhanush Sachin Anthem', N'Dhanush', CAST(3.50 AS Money), 4.45)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Hamari Atariya Pe', N'Rekha Bhardwaj', CAST(4.00 AS Money), 4.43)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Kabhi Jo Badal Barse', N'Arijit Singh', CAST(3.40 AS Money), 5.05)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Do Rang Duniya Ke Aur Do Raste', N'Mukesh', CAST(2.75 AS Money), 4.35)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Mera Joota Hai Japani', N'Mukesh', CAST(1.97 AS Money), 5.15)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Full Jhol', N'Mika Singh, Akasa Singh', CAST(2.45 AS Money), 5.05)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Kaddu Katega', N'Antara Mitra', CAST(3.24 AS Money), 4.25)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Tujse Door Jo Hota Hunn',N'Gajendra Verma', CAST(2.45 AS Money), 3.45)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Chura Liya Hai Tumne Jo Dil Ko',N'Asha Bhosle, Mohammad Rafi', CAST(3.55 AS Money), 4.05)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Title] ([name],[artist], [price], [length]) 
VALUES (N'Deewana Mujh Sa Nahin',N'Mohammad Rafi', CAST(4.35 AS Money), 4.25)
```

The error I'm getting is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkdGX.png)

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are you sure you did it in "Add New Query" and not "Add new table"? Maybe you can only create tables there.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the SQL, check out this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90760/1. This runs on 2008, which should make no difference. So I suggest something else is wrong with where and how you are running it.

Comment: @GrantWinney Nah I tried it with other statements from what I learned and it was fine.

Comment: @rudym I pressed Query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take out the `GO` statement.

Visual Studio / SQL Server Data Tools uses the ADO.NET data provider. `GO` is not recognized by the database engine, only by Management Studio and OSQL/SQLCMD.

[SQL Server GO Keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)